# Highchart fill area only between two series

Tags: highcharts

Here is chart http://jsfiddle.net/erzLp3n9/2/

I need to remove color as this image is seems

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNeXu.png)

I have two different series.

I do not want to use `area-stacked` and `arearange` because that two different series is dynamic.

I had try by this http://jsfiddle.net/erzLp3n9/3/ but not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b3uryhyz/  pass colors

Comment: thanks @Deep3015 but I need to show different area colored only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `negativeFillColor` you can color the area if it is negative, which seems to be the problem with your second example.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erzLp3n9/4/).
Where I set [plotOptions.area.negativeFillColor](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.negativeFillColor).

If you are wondering why they don't look like the same color, it is because the top one is 75% opacity, see [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.fillColor).

Comment: Thanks @ewolden I need same.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain exactly why you do not want to use `stacking`? This option along with setting color of the second series to transparent gives desired effect.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stacking

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xhx34mvg/